# Drawing an array of balls doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to be able to draw an array of balls, I can push the balls into the array (when clicking the canvas).

I can draw 1 of the balls on the canvas if I create it with `ball = new Ball`, but as soon as I try to draw from inside the array it breaks.

I draw inside a `for` loop with `balls[i].draw`

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/7Lmmx/).

And here's the relevant code:

```
function init(){
defaultBall();
    for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
        balls[i].draw;
    }
    ball.draw();
}

function Ball(X, Y, Radius, Color){
    this.X = X || 0;
    this.Y = Y || 0;
    this.radius = 5;
    this.color = Color;
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

var balls = [];

function defaultBall(){
    addBall(new Ball(50, 50, 5, '#6B7E00'));
    addBall(new Ball(150, 50, 5, '#6B7E00'));
}

function addBall(ball){
    balls.push(ball);
}
var ball = new Ball(50, 50, 5, '#6B7E00');
```

How should I formulate the loop to be able to draw the balls?

Help appriciated.

Comment: I meant breaks as in doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: ...right, kind of like defining "bad" as something that is "not good".  Doesn't really help to clear things up does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
balls[i].draw;
```

should be

```
balls[i].draw();
```

on line 4

Answer (score 1):

Your init method isn't getting called again.  If you change

```
function addBall(ball){
    balls.push(ball);
    ball.draw();
}
```

to

```
function addBall(ball){
    balls.push(ball);
}
```

you'll see the new balls.  You need to have some sort of mechanism that calls init (aka draw) again.

And as Frits pointed out you will need to use draw() instead of draw.

Comment: Yeah, I have a interval for the new balls, as you and Frits pointed out it was the missing "()". Such a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs just fine, it is just that there is a small error with your balls loop.

```
defaultBall();
for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
    balls[i].draw;
}
ball.draw();
```

You forgot to use the parenthesis to call the draw method when looping through your balls. The fix is simple:

```
defaultBall();
for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
    balls[i].draw();
}
ball.draw();
```

Note that now your balls will show up as intended. When the fiddle is edited with this new fix for looping through the balls you can see two green balls show up.

Comment: Yeah, slapped myself hard for that one.

Comment: @hustlerinc - The code is quite nice though so don't be too hard on yourself.